# How to get previous cell value in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am creating simple project using Handsontable. For Validations  i need to get previous cell values on **beforeChange** function.
 Here i am getting current focusing  cell value .

this is my code..

```
      beforeChange: function (changes, source) 
         { 
            for (var i = changes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {    

              if (changes[i][3] === "2")//here i am getting current cell value
              { 
                  return true;
              }
           }
         }
```

help me . Thank You..

Comment: Who knows, try `changes[i-1][3]` or `changes[i][2]`

Comment: @adeneo changes[i][2] doesn't work, i checked already

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following page (try editing a value), it should be `changes[i][2]`

- `changes[i][0]` : row
- `changes[i][1]` : property / column
- `changes[i][2]` : previous value
- `changes[i][3]` : new value

http://handsontable.com/demo/callbacks.html

Also it is found here: https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events

> changes is a 2D array containing information about each of the edited
>   cells [ [row, prop, oldVal, newVal], ... ].